# Strip long white spaces when using webpack

Tags: webpack

I have lots of white spaces in my js file, example:

```js
 ${u} </div>\n            <div
```

is there any configuration on webpack which can remove these white spaces?
so output would be? maybe just convert multiple white spaces to one?

```js
${u} </div>\n <div
```

I am using Webpack 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most scenarios, [the `string-replace-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) should work fine. Don't forget to install it first

**Example:**

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: sameTestAsForYourSrcFolderProbably,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        options: {
          // replace multiple non-indent spaces with a single space
          search: /(?<!\n\s*)[ ]+/,
          replace: ' ',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `search` option takes a regex. It looks so complicated because it contains a negative lookbehind to prevent it from gobbling up indentation (that is any whitespace following a new line `\n`).

Good luck!

Comment: thank you, this library is great, I think the regex part is not working `/(?<!\n\s*)[ ]+/` since this one doesnt replace any thing :( I checked with string and it worked fine

Comment: @RainMan That will also kill your indentation, but if it serves, your purpose, go for it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact using Webpack 5 and see whitespaces in your compiled javascript code, I believe you have some faulty setting in your webpack.config file. By default webpack 5 both minifies and strip white-spaces/returns etc. Only exception is within resources or special string values such as what styled components create. However, the latter is easily compressed by gzip.

Have you tried running a build without a config to see what bundle it creates for you?

```
yarn webpack --mode production
```